# View Earth's history through a telescope aimed at a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, estimation, telescopes

If I'm correct in saying that some of the light that left Earth in the past will have reached a black hole event horizon (EH) and that granted, some of the light will enter the EH, but that there will also be some light that skims the EH a bit farther out, gets bent (follows a geodesic) to such a degree as to be **redirected** back to earth, then:

What would be the specifications to a (space-based orbital) telescope capable of resolving say, a hectare on earth if the black hole was 5 light years away (viewing 10 years in the past)?

I imagine that this kind of technology is not going to be possible in the near future, but one must be allowed to dream.

Comment: I haven't done the math on this (and you'd need the size of the black hole to do it precisely), but I'd be shocked if you werent'talking about "less than a single photon" type effects

Comment: Hi Qubit: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: @Qmechanic Is the first step the angular size? In python the angular size can be calculated, `math.degrees(math.atan(100/(9.461*pow(10, 16))))` = 6.06e-14 Degrees. That's 100 metres at 10 light years converted to metres. But I'm sure there are many other factors involved here. Maybe the image is inverted as well?

Comment: I am ignorant on these, but would be considering a mirror change the meaning of your calculation? If not, perhaps the whole calculation could be independent of BH characteristics.

Comment: Are you asking if a sufficiently big black hole (say, several light-days in diameter) could *refocus* the redirected light so that the technical challenges would be less formidable than resolving a hectare-sized patch on another planet from 10 light-years away without the help of a BH?

Comment: Try starting by working out how/if you could resolve one hectare on the Earth from a telescope of some conventional type if you were viewing from 5 light years away.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Could be more, could be less formidable. I imagine, to begin with, just assume the BH redirection works like a mirror? I also imagined that someone might propose an answer which included a solar system sized array of small light detectors, all pointing in exactly the right direction. Maybe I'm out by orders of magnitude? Or it's flat out impossible? We're deep in the realm of science-tech fiction here, so I, for one, will **not** critcise anyone's ideas or answers. But sure, if someone knows how a BH would affect this proposal, I'd love to know.

Comment: @StephenG Do you happen to know where I might find resources to work it out? One of the reasons I came here to ask the question was because I really don't know where to start with the design of a telescope that can view large distances with relatively high resolution.

Comment: The state of the art for this is called [Aperture Synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_synthesis).  Your requirements are well beyond even that.  A conventional telescope is limited by many factors but the best starting point is [Angular Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution).  The amount of light (number of photons per second) reaching your black hole from Earth would be a significant problem in relation to resolving an image, other factors aside.

Comment: @StephenG Thank you. I'm going to try and research the quantity of electromagnetic radiation leaving earth on a _regular_ basis and then try and figure out how much might make the journey. I'll try to include radio and television broadcast frequencies but the most promising for now appears to be [OLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outgoing_longwave_radiation).